# jQuery vertical bubble marquee HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

I'm searching for a good vertical bubble marquee plugin.

Not simple vertical marquee, I'm looking for a good "flash like" effects plugin, something smooth with element marquee from bottom to top of a div content.

Could be really nice but I think it's only in my dreams this plugin

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not terribly efficient, but this is a good start I think:

```
jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function(vertSpeed, horiSpeed) {
    this.css('float', 'left');

    vertSpeed = vertSpeed || 1;
    horiSpeed = 1/horiSpeed || 1;

    var windowH = this.parent().height(),
        thisH = this.height(),
        parentW = (this.parent().width() - this.width()) / 2,
        rand = Math.random() * 1000,
        current = this;

    this.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
    this.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    setInterval(function() {
        current.css({
            marginTop: function(n, v) {
                return parseFloat(v) - vertSpeed;
            },
            marginLeft: function(n, v) {
                return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 1000) + rand) + 1) * parentW;
            }
        });
    }, 15);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
            current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
        }
    }, 250);
};

$('.message').verticalMarquee(0.5, 1);
```

It uses `Math.sin` to move the element horizontally. The function `verticalMarquee` accepts two arguments, one for vertical speed and the other for horizontal speed. The function can only be called on jQuery objects that contains only one element - during testing anything more than one element been animated at once caused terrible amount of lagging.

See a simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/CcccQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [The Silky Smooth Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) plugin?

Comment: i mean i would like somenthing bubbling or with some good effect :P